# Shell script that prints out everyline between the first number(as in firstline) and the second number(last line)?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

The program has to be written with head and tail, but I have no clue how.

**example.txt**:

```
This is line 0
This is line 1
This is line 2
...
This is line 10
```

expect result:

```
$ ./program.sh 1 3 example.txt 
This is line 1
This is line 2
This is line 3
//There also has to be an error message if the first number is greater than the second.
```

Comment: Please, take a look at [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

**program.sh** just like:

```
awk -v first="$1" -v last="$2" 'NR >= first && NR <= last' "$3"
```

Check from **`man awk`**:

**`NR`**: The total number of input records seen so far.

**`-v var=val`**: assign the value val to the variable var, before execution of the program begins.  Such variable values are available to the BEGIN rule of an AWK program.